# testing number of files matching pattern so oldest file can be deleted if there are more than 1

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, zsh

I have a directory containing the following files:

```
test_fed_1.rds
test_fed_2.rds
test_nonfed_1.rds
test_nonfed_2.rds
```

They will be sorted in descending order by last time modified.
I need to test if there are more than one file matching "*test_fed_*" so that I can remove the older of the files, if more than one file matching the given pattern exists.

I currently have the following, which gives me the number of files matching the pattern in the directory:

```
echo ${#$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*test_fed_*")}
```

which gives the output `2`.

I am having trouble incorporating a test for this into a shell if-else statement that sees if there are multiple files matching the pattern, and then, if there are, deletes the older of the files, so that there is only one file (the most recently modified) matching the pattern remaining.

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
if [[${#$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*test_fed_*")} > 1]]
  then ls -t inv_fed_* | tail -n 1 | xargs -d '\n' rm # <- removes last file
fi
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this `zsh`, that shell's [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) make this very simple.

First, store the files you're interested in in an array, sorted in the correct order, and then you can easily check the length of the array and do things like delete the last element or all but the first using array [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt extended_glob

files=( test_fed_*.rds(#qom) ) # Sort by modification time; most recent first

if [[ ${#files} -gt 1 ]]; then # More than one file 
    rm "${files[-1]}" # Delete the oldest one - the last one in the array
    # rm "${files[@]:1}" # Or delete all but the newest/first file.
fi
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn : Do we really need `#q` here? I found that just using `(om)` works fine, without the need of `extended_glob`.

Comment: @user1934428 I prefer the extended glob syntax over the bare glob qual form. (Plus it turns on other useful things.)